# Node server.js throws error - Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend

When I tried to run my node server by this command:

```
node server.js
```

I got this error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'fcc-express-bground'
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the package.

```
npm i fcc-express-bground
```

Answer (score 3):

Install the dependency by running: `npm i fcc-express-background`.